# Java Playing Audio Throwing IOException

Tags: java, audio

After a few hours of searching the internet of how to play audio in Java, trying many different methods, and all of them failing, I decided to make a post. Here is how I am playing the audio:

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(
                        System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/assets/sounds/"
                                + this.firePath);
                AudioStream audioStream = new AudioStream(in);
                AudioPlayer.player.start(audioStream);
```

And here is the exception:

```
java.io.IOException: could not create audio stream from input stream
at sun.audio.AudioStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.hu.weapon.Weapon.fire(Weapon.java:81)
at com.hu.ui.MainGUI$Panel.mousePressed(MainGUI.java:135)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Then either the file does not exist or can't be read for some reason.  Have you tried using `System.out.println(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/assets/sounds/" + this.firePath).exists());` to see if the file you're trying to load actually exists?  Maybe even use `System.out.println(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/assets/sounds/" + this.firePath));` to see what the actual path/name would be?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes, and the file path is valid.

Comment: Then the file is not a valid audio file which the `AudioSystem` can load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never use classes in the `sun.*` package directly, they are not part of the standard JDK...
try

```
File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/assets/sounds/" + this.firePath);
AudioInputStream audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);

AudioFormat format = audioStream.getFormat();
DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);
Clip audioClip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);

audioClip.open(audioStream);
audioClip.start();
```

Two caveat:

- Works with WAV files only
- The audio runs in a different thread, if the application (for instance a SSCCE) terminates right after the `start()` command then the audio playback is killed before starting and you will hear nothing...